# time_format without leading zero on it time

Tags: mysql, concatenation, time-format

i use the function like this

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT("01:02:03", "%H-%i-%s")
```

and get the result `01-02-03` while I do not want leading zeros to be `1-2-3`

i use php and think of using `str_replace()` and `trim()` but i do not know if mysql can do it in short

```
01:02:03 > 1-2-3
00:02:03 > 0-2-3
00:00:03 > 0-0-3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution that I can think of is to concatenate separately the hour, minutes and seconds as integers:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', HOUR('01:02:03'), MINUTE('01:02:03'), SECOND('01:02:03'))
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1052112027143d4c4922ed0a3cd34c97).

Comment: it works until i do have `00:02:03` time

Comment: @Anton you are right. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of [@forpas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69634804), if you don't want the hours or minutes when they are zero; so "2-3" instead of "0-2-3".

I wanted my time in the "1h 2m 3s" format, but to not show the 0 value groupings; so "2m 3s" instead of "0h 2m 3s" and "3s" instead of "0h 0m 3s".

If you have the data in Time format (hh:mm:ss):

```
SELECT IF(TIME_TO_SEC(time_value) >= 3600, CONCAT(HOUR(time_value), '-', MINUTE(time_value), '-', SECOND(time_value)), IF(TIME_TO_SEC(time_value) >= 60, CONCAT(MINUTE(time_value), '-', SECOND(time_value)), SECOND(time_value))) AS formatted_time
```

If you have the data in Seconds (s):

```
SELECT IF(seconds_value >= 3600, CONCAT(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds_value)), '-', MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds_value)), '-', SECOND(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds_value))), IF(seconds_value >= 60, CONCAT(MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds_value)), '-', SECOND(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds_value))), SECOND(SEC_TO_TIME(seconds_value)))) AS formatted_time
```